# Opening lots of files via command line in PhpStorm

Tags: shell, command-line, phpstorm

I use the following bash command to open all the files that differ between my current branch and a specified branch (great for pull request reviews!):

```
git diff --name-only master | xargs -d '\n' pstorm;
```

This works great unless there's over about 10 files.. it only seems to open the last 10 in the list.

I confirmed it was an issue with the `pstorm` script by manually running:

```
pstorm [filepath1] [filepath2] ... [filepath20]
```

Again it only seemed to load the last 10 or 11 files.

I have a hunch this is to do with the string length of the arguments coming into `pstorm`, but my Python knowledge is pretty limited (non existent?)

So my question is: How can I get `pstorm` to open all the files passed to it on the command line?

Comment: Maybe it's not the lenght but whats getting there. Did you check encoding? Are path in the proper form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you were trying using is alright, PhpStorm is configured to keep only first 10 tabs open by default.
You can adjust the limit at `Settings | Editor | General | Editor Tabs | Tab limit`.